# Why when I'm doing a text in a section, it doesn't create paragraphs?

Tags: line-breaking, paragraphs

I have done 1 section called "Ejercicio" which has a textbf inside it and there is no problem, but i have copied it and paste down, but now with text (instead of textbf), and it only create 1 line without doing a simetric paragraph. Im posting an image down:[image]

Comment: `\text` is `\mbox` and prevents linebreaks. Please always show code as text in a code block in the question not as an image. But here your answer is simply to delete `\text`

Comment: Unrelated bu why are you typesetting large portions of text in `\textbf`, that seems to be a bad idea.

Comment: Welcome. // The screenshot is fine for illustration purposes. Please copy your code directly into your question, next time, and tag it as code (using the { } icon after selecting your code).

Answer (score 1):

`\text` is essentially `\mbox` and prevents linebreaks. Simply delete `\text{` and the closing `}`

Comment: @javimp To follow-up: the purpose of `\text` is to typeset some text within a mathematical expression.  Text by itself doesn't need a command.